# how to set gridview Cell back ground color in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 20 rows and 10 column data in Gridview.
I have to set particular cell back ground color Gray like [1 row][1 col],[3 row][1 col].
I have written this line of

```
code.grdsellthru.Rows[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```

but color is applying total row.
I need to apply only 3 rd row 1 column.

Comment: Why do you want to set color of a particular row's column. It is fixed or is on some condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> color is applying total row.I need to apply only 3 rd row 1 column

You need to specify `Cell` along with the Row like:

```
grdsellthru.Rows[3].Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```

Comment: @shankar.parsanamoni, you are welcome, did that sort out your problem ?

Comment: ya,but first time i didn't get that propery in intellisence box.Sorry for that.I will sort out before posting.thanks for gvng suggetion